# Why doesn't my Git pre-commit hook trigger in a cloned repository?

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook

I just wrote small pre-commit hook to perform my custom action. My central repository is on a Solaris server and HTTP enabled.

```
/apps/opt/git/myrepo.git
```

I edited pre-commit hook and modified as below:

```
#!/bin/sh -x
if [ $LOGNAME -ne bala ]; then
   echo  "You are not allowed"
   exit 1;
fi
```

If I clone this repository and perform the commit action using other user, it doesn't give any message, and commits it.
Why is my commit not invoking the `pre-commit` hook?

Also I could see in my cloned repo under `.git/hooks` directory, the "`pre-commit`" hook is not there, I can see only the default templates.

Can anyone help here?

Comment: Did the tips from baluchen help you solving the problem? If yes, could you accept the solution (using the checkmark button)?

Answer (score 7):

Few elements of an answer here:

- Hooks aren't propagated through clones, they are purely local to a repo
- if you clone a repo where you define a hook, you won't find said hook
- if you want to prevent a commit on your local repo, you need a `pre-commit` (like you did) on the local repo. Make sure it is executable.
- if you want to block any commit done by anyone but 'bala', you need a `pre-receive` on the server side

Comment: VonC, Thanks for your update. I didn't knew that hooks never come with clone. 

Is there a way to prevent users deleting this hook? I want to keep these hooks in central location. Apprciate if you can provide possible way to share the hook script.

Comment: @baluchen: that is why I mentioned a server-side hook like `pre-receive`: you cannot prevent a user doing whatever he/she wants on his/her local repo. But at least you can reject commits pushed to your central repo if said commits don't respect certain criteria.

Comment: Thanks VonC. I will try the option